# EF2: Is there a way to add an Entity to EntityCollection without having to load related Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I can set an EntityReference on an entity without having to load the relevent entity as follows:

```
this.CategoryReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("MyEntities.CategorySet", "Id", 12);
```

So I can set the Category for the entity I'm dealing with to whatever category has id 12 without having to hit the database.

But is there a way to do this or something similar on an EntityCollection?  So if I now have multiple categories instead of just one, I want to now do something like the following, though it doesn't work:

```
// stand-in category
var categoryStandIn = new Category { EntityKey = new EntityKey("MyEntities.CategorySet", "Id", 12) }
this.Categories.Add(categoryStandIn);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [EntityCollections setting an EntityReference.EntityKey to populate the Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410741/entitycollections-setting-an-entityreference-entitykey-to-populate-the-collection)

Comment: Yep, it is indeed a duplicate. Seems I just didn't quite know how to ask the question, so my previous searching didn't find that one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a simular question.  Use [stub entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities).

[EntityCollections setting an EntityReference.EntityKey to populate the Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410741/entitycollections-setting-an-entityreference-entitykey-to-populate-the-collection)

Comment: Thank you John! I had tried that previously, but the comments in the blog you linked contained the clues I needed to fix it - turns out the entity I was trying to add had already been loaded so I had to call ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry before doing the AttachTo to check if it was already loaded - if already loaded use the loaded entity, if not use the stub.